# how to configure azure module in ansible

Tags: azure, ansible

As mention on subject,I want to configure azure module in ansible, also find out azure module in github but i don't not how to setup, please help me to install and configure.

Comment: What is your problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have installed ansible latest version in ubuntu and now i want to manage azure cloud using ansible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you need to install `sudo pip install azure==0.11.1`(newest azure version > 1.0  not compatible with ansible yet here is github issue https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/2114)
- Now you need to create Storage_account in the azure console(and later specify it in the playbook)
- Generate ssh key for VM

`openssl req -x509 -key ~/.ssh/id_rsa -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out ~/.ssh/ssh_key.pem`

- Give owner-only permissions for generated key

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/ssh_key.pem`

- Upload this certificate to your azure subscription. I did it via node azure-cli

  `yum install npm or apt-get install npm`

  `nsudo npm install -g azure-cli`

  `azure account download`
- downloading your subscription file by displayed link.

  `azure account import <path to downloaded file>`
- Export manage certificate for your subscription

  `azure account cert export -f ~/.ssh/manage.cer`
- Also I needed to get VM image name via azurecli because I could not find it in the azure console.

`azure vm image list | grep CentOS`

then you need to write playbook which will launch azure VM:

```
- local_action:
    module: azure
    name: 'vm_name'
    role_size: Small
    image: '5112500ae3b842c8b9c604889f8753c3__OpenLogic-CentOS-67-20150815'
    password: 'some_pass'
    location: 'East US 2'
    user: admin
    wait: yes
    subscription_id: 'some subscription'    
    management_cert_path: '~/.ssh/manage.cer'
    storage_account: 'some account'
    endpoints: '22,8080,80'
  register: azure_vm


- add_host:
    name: '{{ azure_vm.public_dns_name }}'

- name: wait when instance become ready to use
  wait_for:
   host: '{{ azure_vm.public_dns_name }}'
   port: "22"
   delay: "60"
   timeout: "320"
   state: "started"
```

This playbook will create Centos6 machine with `admin` user and `password`. Currently I could not create machine with ssh-key authentication. I'm keep getting `msg: password parameter is required for new instance`

UPDATED: Fixed certificate generation procedure.

Comment: I am also getting "ERROR: password is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler" error... Is this latest Azure module?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see from github issue above this module already updating and waiting for a pull request.

Still, if you need a example of provisioning AzureVM with ansible you can check my repository https://github.com/Trane9991/WebGoat-Ansible I just updated everything to working condition(including README).