# Azure cloud service using Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-cloud-services

Is there any way to create a cloud service in Azure using one of the modules? The only module that is working with Azure doesn't allow to create cloud service it's only allowing to create VM's it's assuming that I've already created a cloud service.
I'm trying to deploy a Java-based application using Jetty web service on a Windows machine.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

At present, there isn't any way to create an Azure Cloud Service to host Web or Worker Roles using Ansible.

Having said that (now you've updated your question ;-) you can deploy IaaS VM's using Ansible and then use Ansible to deploy your Java-based application using Jetty w/s on the newly created IaaS VM.

There is a good run-down of how to do this over on this SO question: [How To Configure Azure Module in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907501/how-to-configure-azure-module-in-ansible)

Comment: What is the best practice of deploying to Azure using Ansible ? Should I call external scripts via Ansible that will create the Cloud Service ? BTW, I'm deploying a Java application, maybe I'm making a wrong choice by using Ansible ..

Comment: Could you update your question to explain where you are deploying your Java application within Azure? What are you trying to achieve?