# Can't provide credentials to Ansible Azure module

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm trying to manage my Azure cloud with Ansible module with no luck using the [official guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_azure.html).

I've set Service Principal and got credentials, then put them to file $HOME/.azure/credentials as advised:

```
[default]
subscription_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
client_id=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
tenant=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When start test playbook I've got:
"No subscription_id provided. Please set 'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID' or use the 'subscription_id' parameter"

Then I've set environment variables:

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
export AZURE_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
export AZURE_TENANT=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now I've got the error:
"No management_cert_path provided. Please set 'AZURE_CERT_PATH' or use the 'management_cert_path' parameter"

I can successfully log in into my application with Azure CLI:

```
azure account show
info:    Executing command account show
data:    Name                        : Visual Studio Enterprise: BizSpark
data:    ID                          : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
data:    State                       : Enabled
data:    Tenant ID                   : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
data:    Is Default                  : true
data:    Environment                 : AzureCloud
data:    Has Certificate             : No
data:    Has Access Token            : Yes
data:    User name                   : xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
data:    
info:    account show command OK
```

My test playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Azure VM creation
      azure:
        name: Test_machine
        role_size: Basic_A0
        image:
          offer: CentOS
          publisher: OpenLogic
          sku: '7.1'
          version: latest
        location: 'West Europe'
        user: admin
        password: Password!
        storage_account: my-storage-account
        wait: yes
```

p.s. The receipt listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907501/how-to-configure-azure-module-in-ansible) is not suitable to my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to configure azure module in ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907501/how-to-configure-azure-module-in-ansible)

Comment: Don't believe the docs. Use only `AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` and `AZURE_CERT_PATH`, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907501/how-to-configure-azure-module-in-ansible).

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I've examined both links carefully before posting. They are not my case. This question is not duplicate.

Comment: Ok, did you try to use pem certificate?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I don't need to. I'm using Azure in ARM mode and there are no 'azure account download' nor 'azure account import' commands there at all. Your second link is probably outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `azure` module is the legacy Service Management module, and will likely be deprecated in Ansible 2.2. Sounds like you're already using ARM, and the guide you're referring to is about ARM, so you should be using the [azure_rm_virtualmachine](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html) module instead.

Comment: Updated link: [azure_rm_virtualmachine module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_virtualmachine_module.html)